# Gram Schmidt Process verification

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Use the Gram-Schmidt process to generate an orthogonal set from the given linearly independent vectors:

$w_1=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$w_2=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   2 \\
   1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$w_3=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

So I said $u_1=w_1$ and $u_2=w_2-{u_1^T w_2 \over u_1^T u_1}u_1=w_2$

$u_2=\begin{bmatrix}
   -1 \\
   1 \\
   1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

But I know $u_2=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   -1 \\
   -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Ignore the answer key. Proceed as you were doing, find $u_3$ then compare your answer to the one given. And in the third line you have a typo, it should be $u_2=w_2-u_1$.

Comment: To clarify @GitGud's comment slightly: the formula with a fraction in it is correct, but you computed the fraction wrong: it's not 0, it's "1", so it should read $u_2 = w_2 - (\text{fraction})u_1 = w_2 - u_1$.

Comment: You are right.  Their $u_2$ is the negative of your $u_2$.  Both are orthogonal to $u_1$, but yours is the one you get doing Gram-Schmidt.